# NotSupportedException when doing a Bing image search programatically

Tags: c#, search, bing

I am using the following code to get more than 50 results from a Bing image search using the Bing Search Container for the Bing API.  My problem is that when I try and execute another query (`query.Excecute()`) after changing the off-set to get the next 50 results `("$skip", 50)` I get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll

I can't figure out how to do another query.  Just to re-iterate this occurs when the when the for loop executes the second time.  This happens on this line `var results = query.Execute();` and when it tries the query.

```
   void bingSearch(string searchTerm)
        {
            try
            {
                imageSet = new List<Bing.ImageResult>();
                const string bingKey = "[key]";
                var bing = new BingSearchContainer(
                new Uri("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/")) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(bingKey, bingKey) };                
                var query = bing.Image("\"" + searchTerm + "\"" + "(" + site1 + ")", null, null, null, null, null, ImageFilters);
                Debug.Print("Full Search: " + query.ToString());
                int length = 3;
                int resultsPage = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    query = query.AddQueryOption("$top", 50);
                    query = query.AddQueryOption("$skip", resultsPage);
                    var results = query.Execute();
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (var result in results)
                    {
                        imageSet.Add(result);
                        Debug.Print("URL: " + imageSet[index].Title);
                        index++;
                    }
                    resultsPage = resultsPage + 50;
                    Debug.Print("Getting Next Page: " + resultsPage);
               }
                Debug.Print("Results: " + imageSet.Count);
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Print("Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: what is the message of the exception? which line throws the exception?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and amending my title.  The exception is specifically on this line.  _italic_**bold** 'code' var results = query.Execute();